# Does anyone one who has understood the Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets file provide a minimal msbuild project file to compile a simple WPF application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, msbuild

I am learning VB.net and other stuff. I have a simple interface defined by the following XAML file (`sourceCode.xaml`):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="MyButton"
                Content="Button"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="26,27,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="75"
                Click="MyButton_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="MyLabel"
                Content=""
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="26,73,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see it has just a button and a label. Pressing the button puts "Hello world" in the label using the following handler (`sourceCode.vb`):

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        AddHandler MyButton.Click, AddressOf Me.MyButton_Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        MyLabel.Content = "Hello world"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone help me write a simple MSBuild XML file that can compile this to create an application?

Previously for applications without an interface XAML file, I was using the following to compile:

```
vbc -target:exe -out:code.exe sourceCode.vb
```

Which can also be done using an MSBuild project file like follows (`sourceCode.msbuild`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="sourceCode.vb"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <Vbc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="code.exe"/>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

and calling it using:

```
MSBuild.exe sourceCode.msbuild -target:Build
```

But how do I change this MSBuild file to compile the above program with the XAML interface? Note if there is a way to call the vbc compiler directly using the command line then please share that as well.

Note I am looking for a minimal MSBuild file and not one generated by Visual Studio since it refers to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets` which is too complicated for me to understand. I am quite sure a very small subset of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets` file is actually needed to compile this simple code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-using-msbuild?view=vs-2019

Comment: I think trying for a minimal file will be more trouble than it's worth, because as soon as you try to build a WPF app, you have a bunch of references you need to pull in.  You will add compile items for the code-behind for the xaml files (typically tagged as `<DependentUpon>{xaml file}</DependentUpon>`).  The xaml files themselves are `Page` items typically with `<SubType>Designer</Subtype>` and `<Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>`.

Comment: This doesn't even get into resources or any of the necessary property settings.

Comment: Whoever was suggesting to remove C# tag please note that as far as I understand c# and vb.net build process appear to be identical, looking at the associated .proj and .targets file. So I want to keep that tag since if a c# person provides an answer for c# then it will be less effort to translate it into vb.net.

Comment: @Craig Well I want to understand the build process and if there is an answer to this question then it will help me understand the magic, visual studio does and what files are actually involved in the build process. Right now it is just a black box to me. Also, I am suspicious that Microsoft has made the build process intentionally convoluted to force people to use visual studio. Beside visual studio is not installed on my system since I don't have the space or performance to run it. I just have VS code and vbc.exe and MSBuild.exe that ships with .NET framework.

Comment: @Craig also I don't like useless complications like debug or release mode and creation of sub directories, assembly version numbering etc. I just want a simple, minimal build script that just creates the application in the same folder as the source files without making directories and moving files around and making copies of the same executable in different locations and also adding additional files for debugging purposes which I don't want. VS has become like Photoshop, even if I want to use only .01% of the core features it is forcing me to deal with the baggage of things I will never use.